# Unknown Action for Followers on UsersController - Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm trying to implement a Follower system similar to Twitter in my app. I'm implementing the Follower system explained in Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users

I have noticed an issue after completing the example:

Going to /users/(id)/following or /users/(id)/followers displays the following error messages:

```
Unknown action

The action 'following' could not be found for UsersController
```

or

```
Unknown action

The action 'followers' could not be found for UsersController
```

What puzzles me about these errors is that I did define these actions in the UsersController:

```
def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end
```

Here is my routes.rb file just in case the issue lies there:

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do

  #get "users/index"

  #get "users/show"



authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :works
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Additional information: I'm using Devise to handle user authentication.

FIXED:

The issue was the placement of the following and followed actions in the Users Controller.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/routes.rb`, the member actions must be one per line:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following
    get :followers
  end
end
```

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made the change but I'm still seeing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :users do
  member do
 get  :following 
 get  :followers
    end

 end
```

the above routes work, and provide `following_user_path` and `followers_user_path` routes respectively

Comment: It has to be per line